# if then statement in PeopleSoft Query

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I'm new to PeopleSoft and SQL and need some help figuring this out.

I'm trying to figure out how to best write a query using an if-then type of statement in PS Query. I think a case statement should work.

Criteria to meet (this is the part where I am stuck):
IF Field ACTION = TER then field DEPTID <> 140, 652, 653, 997

My Case Statement: 
Case when A.ACTION = 'TER' then A.DEPTID not in ('140','652','653','997') end

If it will, I am not sure how to use it in my SQL statement. I tried using this in a sub-query and in an expression, but it did not work.

When I tried adding this case statement into the criteria as an expression, the PS Query tool throws this error:

Error Position: 347  Return: 905 - ORA-00905: missing keyword 
Failed

I don't know which keyword is missing.

My query, so far:

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
    PS_JOB A, 
    PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY A1, 
    PS_COL_HR_WF_ROLE B, 
    PS_NAMES_VW C, 
    PS_NAMES_VW D, 
    PS_PER_ORG_ASGN E, 
    PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY E1, 
    PS_ACTN_REASON_TBL F, 
    PS_ACTION_TBL G
  WHERE ( A.EMPLID = A1.EMPLID
    AND A.EMPL_RCD = A1.EMPL_RCD
    AND ( A.ACTION_DT = TO_DATE('2016-07-19','YYYY-MM-DD')
     AND A.EMPL_RCD = B.EMPL_RCD
     AND A.DEPTID <> '997'
     AND A.REG_TEMP = 'R'
     AND A.FULL_PART_TIME = 'F'
     AND B.ROLENAME = 'name of role'
     AND B.ACTION = A.ACTION
     AND B.ACTION_REASON = A.ACTION_REASON
     AND C.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
     AND C.NAME_TYPE = 'PRI'
     AND D.NAME_TYPE = 'PRI'
     AND A.SUPERVISOR_ID = D.EMPLID
     AND E.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
     AND E.EMPL_RCD = A.EMPL_RCD
     AND F.ACTION = B.ACTION
     AND F.ACTION_REASON = B.ACTION_REASON
     AND G.ACTION = F.ACTION
```

)) 
 The preceding braces are moved after END (below) when I use the following case statement in an expression, and the case follows the last line: AND G.ACTION = F.ACTION.

```
AND A.ACTION = Case when  A.ACTION = 'TER' then  A.DEPTID not in ('140','652','653','997') end ))
```

I am quite new to this, and any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, in a combined statement without using CASE, it is implementing

1. A.ACTION IS NOT EQUAL TO 'TER'

OR

2. A.ACTION IS NULL

OR

3. A.ACTION IS EQUAL TO 'TER' AND A.DEPTID IS NOT IN LIST

`AND (A.ACTION != 'TER' OR A.ACTION IS NULL OR (A.ACTION = 'TER' and A.DEPTID NOT IN ('140','652','653','997'))`

Comment: Hi, this ran without errors. I'll verify with my mentor next week that the returned results are what we expect.   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The THEN-keyword in CASE expects a value, you are giving it another condition.

I am not completely sure what you want your condition to be.
I assume you mean that when ACTION='TER', then you want to filter rows with DEPTID in ('140','652','653','997').

One way of doing it could be achieved by adding this to your filter predicates:

```
1 = (CASE WHEN A.ACTION = 'TER' AND A.DEPTID in ('140','652','653','997')
          THEN 0
          ELSE 1
      END)
```

Comment: Hi, I wrote the criteria exactly as it was passed on to me:

I interpreted this statement:
IF Field ACTION = TER then field DEPTID <> 140, 652, 653, 997

to mean:
if A.ACTION = 'TER' then A.DEPTID not in ('140','652','653','997')

therefore, I wrote my case statement as:

AND A.ACTION = 
Case 
 when  A.ACTION = 'TER' 
 then  A.DEPTID not in ('140','652','653','997') 
end ))